# how to install php-qt

Tags: php

Hi can anybody tell me how to install PHP-qt on my system local server. 
my configuration is --
OS     - Widows XP-SP2
server - easyPHP

also is this project php-qt is still "ON" for future , Please send a demo link for it

any alternative for it is most welcome , if there is alternative Please send a demo link and a bit of information.

Answer (score 1):

i think you must compile it from source code to get the extension you need accordig the target OS (.dll in your case)